# Dynamic Check Box CSS & Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to replace a custom image instead of the standard checkbox, I tried a lot of ways but I am unable to, I have already used :checked. Here is the below sample code.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <img src="assets/settings.png" alt="" width="70px;"/>
     <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3" id="cjecg"> &nbsp;
</label>
```

I have 4 such checkbox, I want them to be replace with other image on check.

Answer (score 0):

See demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/s5L02bck/

HTML :

```
<p class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" class="inlineCheckbox" value="option3" id="cb1">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_settings_48px-128.png" alt="" width="70px;"/>
  <label for="cb1"> Option 1 </label>
</p>
```

You will use :checked like this

```
.inlineCheckbox:checked{
  display:none;
}
.inlineCheckbox:checked + img{
  display:inline-block;
}
```